# Correlación 2 D en java no funciona

Tags: java, bucles, matrices

actualmente me encuentro practicando algo básico en lo que vendría siendo java, se me pide que halle la correlación de 2 matrices, matriz A y Matriz B, A la hora de hallar el promedio todo esta bien el problema viene cuando quiero hallar Amn y Bmn ya que dicho valor me da 0.
La formula que estoy utilizando es:

[image: Formula correlacion 2D]

Lo primero que hice fue declarar las variables de lass matrices tanto A como B de tipo double y declaro algunas variables que voy a utilizar acontinuacion

```
public class Principal {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double [][] matrizA = {{1, 6}, {2, 4}};
    double [][] matrizB = {{3, 4}, {5, 3}};

    double suma1 = 0, suma2 = 0;
    double cEl1 = 0, cEl2 = 0;
    double num1 = 0, num2 = 0, den1 = 0, den2 =0, dentotal;
    double numtotal ;
    double numeroA2 = 0, numeroA = 0, numeroB2 = 0, numeroB = 0;
```

Despues creo un ciclo for anidado en otro ciclo for que recorra la matriz para hallar el promedio de dicha matriz En este caso primero la matriz A, despues de hallar el promedio necesito hallar el num1 y num2 donde estos son num1 = (Amn - A) en la matriz A respectivamente

```
{
        //numerador 1
        for (int fA = 0; fA < nfilasA; fA++) {
            for (int cA = 0; cA < ncolumnasA; cA++) {
                numeroA = (matrizA[fA][cA]);
                suma1 = suma1 + numeroA;
                cEl1 = cEl1 + 1;
                System.out.println("suma1: "+ suma1 +" cantel1: "+ cEl1);
            }
        }
        double promedioA = suma1 / cEl1;
        System.out.println("suma1: " + suma1 + " promedio1: " + promedioA);
        for (int fA = 0; fA < nfilasA; fA++) {
            for (int cA = 0; cA < ncolumnasA; cA++) {
                numeroA2 = (matrizA[fA][cA]);
                num1 = num1 + ( numeroA2 - promedioA);
                den1 = den1 + Math.pow(num1, 2);


            }
        }
        System.out.println("num1: "+ num1 +" den1: "+ den1);
        System.out.println("numero A2: "+ numeroA2);
```

y num2 = (Bmn - B) en la matriz B respectivamente

```
        {
        //numerador 2
        for (int fB = 0; fB < nfilasB; fB++) {
            for (int cB = 0; cB < ncolumnasB; cB++) {
                numeroB = (matrizB[fB][cB]);
                suma2 = suma2 + numeroB;
                cEl2 = cEl2 + 1;
                System.out.println("suma2: "+ suma2 +" cantel2: "+ cEl2);
            }
        }
        double promedioB = suma2 / cEl2;
        System.out.println("suma1: " + suma2 + " promedio1: " + promedioB);
        for (int fB = 0; fB < nfilasB ; fB++) {
            for (int cB = 0; cB < ncolumnasB; cB++) {
                numeroB2 = (matrizB[fB][cB]);
                num2 = num2 + ( numeroB2 - promedioB);
                den2 = den2 + Math.pow(num2, 2);


            }
        }
        System.out.println("num2: "+ num2 +" den2: "+ den2);
        System.out.println("numero B2: "+ numeroB2);
    }
```

A la hora de ejecutar el promedio se calcula de forma correcta, pero a la hora de calcular el num1 y num2 estos dan 0 respectivamente, haciendo que toda la ecuación de la correlación de 0 sin importar que valores tengan las matrices

Despues de hallar promedio y num1 y num2(que como digo me dan 0) termino el código ejecutando las ultimas operaciones de la formula y imprimiendo los datos:

```
        numtotal = ( num1 *  num2);
    dentotal =  (Math.sqrt(den1 * den2));
    double corr2d =  (numtotal / dentotal);
    System.out.println("numtotal: "+ numtotal);
    System.out.println("dentotal: "+ dentotal);
    System.out.println("La correlacion entre la matrizA y la matrizB es: "+ corr2d);
}
```

}

Y bueno en realidad no se muy bien que estoy haciendo mal, se que es algo básico pero estoy aprendiendo, agradezco su ayuda.

PD: estaba probando algunas cosas y paso algo curioso que cambie:

```
for (int fA = 0; fA < nfilasA; fA++) {
            for (int cA = 0; cA < ncolumnasA; cA++) {
                numeroA2 = (matrizA[fA][cA]);
                num1 = num1 + ( numeroA2 - promedioA);
                den1 = den1 + Math.pow(num1, 2);
```

por

```
for (int fA = 0; fA < nfilasA; fA++) {
            for (int cA = 0; cA < ncolumnasA; cA++) {
                numeroA2 = (matrizB[fA][cA]);
                num1 = num1 + ( numeroA2 - promedioA);
                den1 = den1 + Math.pow(num1, 2);
```

Esto en la matriz de A para hallar el numerador de esta misma cambiando `numeroA2 = (matrizA[fA][cA]);` por `numeroA2 = (matrizB[fA][cA]);` hice esto igual en matriz B, cambiando `numeroA2 = (matrizB[fB][cB]);` por `numeroA2 = (matrizA[fB][cB]);` esta vez tanto num1 y num 2 obtuvieron un valor diferente de 0 por ente la correlación se pudo realizar, pero no creo que esto este bien, bueno en ojala puedan responderme :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Lees mal la fórmula.

Te pongo el ejemplo como un array unidimensional pero el concepto es el mismo. Am es la media de A.

Lo que haces es el *sumatorio(Ai - Am)* multiplicado por el *sumatorio(Bi - Bm)*.

Pero

> *sumatorio(Ai - Am) =
>
> sumatorio(Ai) - sumatorio(Am) =
>
> sumatorio(Ai) - Am * n* (porque Am es constante)

Pero claro, *Am* se define como *sumatorio(Ai) / n*.

Así que

> *sumatorio(Ai - Am) =
>
> sumatorio(Ai) - sumatorio(Am) =
> sumatorio(Ai) - Am * n =
>
> sumatorio(Ai) - sumatorio(Ai) * n / n =
>
> sumatorio(Ai) - sumatorio(Ai)*

#### ¡Te tiene que dar cero a la fuerza!

Por supuesto, lo mismo pasa con B.

Lo que la fórmula pide es *sumatorio((Ai-Am) * (Bi-Bm))* , que no es lo que tienes implementado.

Comment: Va, no lo he entendido a la primera, pero volví a leer y resolviste lo que necesitaba, es cierto que simplemente estaba haciendo sumatorio((Ai-Am) * (Bi-Bm)) de manera independiente y por eso no me daba el resultado que como dices tenia que dar 0 por ese error, ya implementado la formula como dices funciono, muchas gracias.